# Pantheon Shell Loading So Slow

Tags: pantheon

I just did system update on Loki from AppCenter. But after restarting, the shell (Pantheon?) loads really, really slow. It was fast before.

Here my syslog, maybe it helps:  https://pastebin.com/UQKYeCeh

I hope someone can help since I don't have any idea what's causing it.

Thank you in advance!﻿

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are running into a known issue, that many of us encountered already.
Please run this command from the terminal.

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.backup
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: After restarting few times to make sure, I can confirm the command above works. Thank you, Mike! Btw, I still get a lot of warnings in my syslog like before. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: i know how to turn these warnings off, however i don't think it actually resolves the issue that warnings warn about.. if you want I can look it up

Comment: Well, let's just wait for the real fix for that issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently a issue with dbus, more information: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/143

See Mike Rodov answer for the work around.