# HUGE problem when trying to login!

Tags: greeter

when I try to login, the process starts, but when only the background is shown, it gets stuck. nothing works, the plank and the wing-panel do not show and no matter what button I press, nothing happens. the only way to login again is to force restart the computer, but when I try to login again the same process occurs again and this can happen for many times over until it finally logs in.

This problem has really been bugging me now and has become  ***really***  annoying. is there anyway in which i can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a known bug, and actually if you wait for a few minutes (depends on the machine) it will start

however there's a workaround

I described it in [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/12439/8520)