# elmenetary os. loki 0.4.1. stable 64 bit isnt running

Tags: system-installation, settings, wingpanel

for the past 10 years i am using  Linux privat and busines on different PC (Ubuntu,Mint,Bodhi, open suse etc.) but with elementary there is a new situation. I am unable to keep this distro running.
After installation elementary tweeks wing menue disappeared. I tried every  help site deinstall / install etc. and now there is no panel and no terminal.
This is the second try with elemetary maybee this Distro is only for developer not for advanced User.
Situations with personalizing linux are common, but there are soluitions.

Maybe there is somewhere somebody who knows help

Comment: what do you mean tweak menu?  are you facing something like: after login there's just the desktop picture?

Comment: I tried to install tweaks. Now there is only the desktop picture. Biggest problem Terminal doesnt open.

Comment: before this situation i tried all help / Solutions sites for elementary.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but an installation of Elementary Tweaks can only be done via PPA. PPAs are disabled on Elementary by default because they can cause system issues, like this one.

Comment: "After installation elementary tweeks wing menue disappeared. I tried every help site deinstall / install etc. and now there is no panel and no terminal."
So, did you try an incompatible theme with Tweaks? That would explain the disappearing Wingpanel. Then you "deinstalled/installed" what exactly? ("every help site" isn't very specific either) Seems you shot up your system quite thoroughly. How can that be the fault of the system? I'm on Linux for 1.5 yrs now and Loki runs stable as can be. WITH elementary Tweaks and a GTK+ 3.18 theme. Try `sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened before you installed tweaks however there's [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12430/pantheon-shell-loading-so-slow) issue with Elementary that sounds similar to your issue

You can boot with installation USB and run the command in the thread 
just change the paths to the ones that match your installation

**in general I have to say the ElOS is anything but complicated, it's smooth and fun. there are some bugs, like in any other sw**

Comment: can not start etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop : No such file or directory

Comment: tried today with Terminal strg+alt+F1 before login sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily

Comment: then add new ppasudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks &&
sudo apt update &&
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks

Comment: Situation unchanged

Comment: i think you are right Elementary Os is anything but complicated. This is my second try with Elementary and i am unable to keep this OS running.

Comment: I am using daily Bodhi there are bugs too i can handle these. I love  the possibilities with linux distroś. On my new lenovo all in one touchscreen schould Loki replace windows 10. Maybe i use one old desktop to play with loki and try to handle it. In Moment i need a running distro and its not elementary OS. I am thankful for your help.

Comment: Sure, sorry that you had to drop it. I;m running it on 2 laptops (one is my work machine) and on one desktop and they all run well (excluding minor issues that are present in any distro)

Answer (score -1):

Also ich würde komplett neu installieren. Außerdem auf alle ppas verzichten.Benutze selbst elementary seit Luna auf 4 Rechnern 3 HP + 1 Mac mini sicher es hat seine kleinen Macken aber im großen und ganzen äußerster 
stabil. 1.neues ISO herunterladen mit Etcher USB-Stick beschreiben. Partitionieren normal. Nach Installation aktualisieren dann erst Sprachpakete bearbeiten.Eigentlich müsste es ohne besondere Mühe dann tadellos laufen.

Tranlated to English: 
So I would completely reinstall. In addition, on all ppas dispense. Use self elementary since Luna on 4 calculators 3 HP + 1 Mac mini secure it has its small quirks but on the whole extreme stable. 1.download new ISO with another USB-stick. Partitioning normally. After installation update then only language packages to edit. It would really have to run without special effort then perfectly.